# How to know what text has been deleted from a JTextPane

Tags: swing

I have added a document listener to a JTextPane.  I want to know what text has been added or removed so I can take action if certain key words are entered.  The insert part works just fine, but I do not know how to detect what text was deleted.

The insert works because the text is there and I can select it, but the delete has already removed the text so I get bad location exceptions sometimes.

I want to make reserved words that are not inside quotes bold so I need to know what has been removed, removing even one character (like a quote) could have a huge impact.

My code follows:

```
    @Override
public void insertUpdate(DocumentEvent e)
{
    Document doc = e.getDocument();
    String i = ""; 

    try
    {
        i = doc.getText(e.getOffset(), e.getLength());
    }
    catch(BadLocationException e1)
    {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }

    System.out.println("INSERT:" + e + ":" + i);
}

@Override
public void removeUpdate(DocumentEvent e)
{
    Document doc = e.getDocument();
    String i = ""; 

    try
    {
        i = doc.getText(e.getOffset(), e.getLength());
    }
    catch(BadLocationException e1)
    {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }

    System.out.println("REMOVE:" + e + ":" + i);
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is strange that there is no simple way to get this information.

I've looked at the source code of Swing libraries for this. Of course - there is this information in `DocumentEvent`, which is of class `AbstractDocument$DefaultDocumentEvent`, which contains `protected Vector<UndoableEdit> edits`, which contains one element of type `GapContent$RemoveUndo`, which contains `protected String string` that is used only in this class (no other "package" classes get this) and this `RemoveUndo` class have no getter for this field.

Even `toString` didn't show it (because `RemoveUndo` hasn't overrided `toString` method):

```
[javax.swing.text.GapContent$RemoveUndo@6303ddfd hasBeenDone: true alive: true]
```

This is so strange for me that I belive that there is some other easy way to get the removed string and that I just don't know how to accomplish it.

One thing you can do is the most obvious:

```
    final JTextArea textArea = new JTextArea();
    textArea.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
            previousText = textArea.getText();
        }
    });

    textArea.getDocument().addDocumentListener(new DocumentListener() {
        @Override
        public void removeUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
            if(previousText != null) {
                String removedStr = previousText.substring(e.getOffset(), e.getOffset() + e.getLength());
                System.out.println(removedStr);
            }
        }
        @Override
        public void insertUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
        }
        @Override
        public void changedUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
        }
    });
```

where `previousText` is an instance variable.

or (the most nasty ever):

```
textArea.getDocument().addDocumentListener(new DocumentListener() {
        @Override
        public void removeUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
            String removedString = getRemovedString(e);
            System.out.println(removedString);
        }

        @Override
        public void insertUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
        }

        @Override
        public void changedUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
        }
    });
```

plus this method:

```
public static String getRemovedString(DocumentEvent e) {
    try {
        Field editsField = null;
        Field[] fields = CompoundEdit.class.getDeclaredFields();
        for(Field f : fields) {
            if(f.getName().equals("edits")) {
                editsField = f;
                break;
            }
        }
        editsField.setAccessible(true);
        List edits = (List) editsField.get(e);
        if(edits.size() != 1) {
            return null;
        }

        Class<?> removeUndo = null;
        for(Class<?> c : GapContent.class.getDeclaredClasses()) {
            if(c.getSimpleName().equals("RemoveUndo")) {
                removeUndo = c;
                break;
            }
        }

        Object removeUndoInstance = edits.get(0);
        fields = removeUndo.getDeclaredFields();

        Field stringField = null;
        for(Field f : fields) {
            if(f.getName().equals("string")) {
                stringField = f;
                break;
            }
        }

        stringField.setAccessible(true);
        return (String) stringField.get(removeUndoInstance);
    }
    catch(SecurityException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch(IllegalArgumentException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch(IllegalAccessException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: That is nasty. :)  Not sure what I will do in the end but thanks a bunch for the effort.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem than you. And what Xeon explained help me a lot too. But after, i found a way to do that. In my case, i created a custom StyledDocument class that extends DefaultStyledDocument:

```
   public class CustomStyledDocument extends DefaultStyledDocument
    {


        public CustomStyledDocument () {
           super();
    }

     @Override
        public void insertString(int offset, String string, AttributeSet as) throws BadLocationException {
            super.insertString(offset, string, as);
    }

    @Override
        public void remove(int offset, int i1) throws BadLocationException { 
        String previousText = getText(offset, i1);
        super.remove(offset, i1);
    }

}
```

So if you call getText method before you call super.remove(...), you will get the previous text.